# How can I turn this into a function that takes 2 arguments - a sentence and then the word I want to count in the string?

Tags: javascript, string, function

I am a newbie here. I had a technical assessment the other day and had a coding question where I had to write a function that took two arguments, a sentence and a word. The function had to count how many times the word was repeated in the sentence. I have managed to get the answer doing it the first way you see below but cannot for the life of me seem to figure it out as a function that takes 2 arguments which is what the task asked for. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

```js
let count = 0;
let str = "hello hello hello Bob is my name so it is hello"
let query = "hello";
let array = str.split(" ")
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] === query) {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

```js
let str = "hello my name is my my bob";
let word = "my";

function countWord(str, word) {
  let count = 0;
  let strArray = str.split(" ");
  let array = strArray;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === word) {
      count++
    }
  }
}
console.log(countWord(str, word));
```

Comment: The function is missing the `return count` statement at the end. How did you expect the value to get to the caller?

Comment: What's the reason for `let array = strArray;`? Why not just use `let array = str.split(" ");`?

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is that you're missing `return count` at the end of your function.

```js
const sentence = 'hello there this is another hello hello test hello';
const word = 'hello';

function testString (sen, word) {
  const split = sen.split(' ');
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (split[i] === word) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(testString(sentence, word));
```

Comment: This answer seems like overkill. There's no need to restyle the function when the only thing wrong is that it's missing `return count`

Comment: Admittedly I didn't see OPs attempt at writing the function the first time, skimmed over as I've seen many "newbie's" (as the OP described themselves) double post their code and it wasn't separated into individual code blocks. This was my own go at it with no reference to their original attempt. Will reformat now tho.

Comment: Yeah, it was hard to tell that he put both the non-function and functions in the same snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this requirement with a single line of code using `regex`.

**Demo :**

```js
let str = "hello my name is my my bob";
let word = "my";

console.log(str.match(new RegExp('\\b'+word+'\\b','g')).length);
```

Comment: @Aisha please do accept this answer if it helps. So that it can help other developers as well.